# Does PIPE_BUF apply to named pipes aka FIFOs?

Tags: unix, concurrency, buffer, named-pipes

What I read today about UNIX's pipes:

> If multiple processes are writing to a single pipe, then it is
>   guaranteed that their data won’t be intermingled if they write no more
>   than PIPE_BUF bytes at a time.

Does it apply to named pipes also known as FIFOs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, FIFOs behave like pipes in that regard, and POSIX states that PIPE_BUF applies to them.